# How to fuse maps constructed by two different sensors？

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw in the paper that the Bayesian filtering method can be used to fuse the two maps. For example, I used a depth camera and a lidar to build their own maps. I don't quite understand how Bayesian filters fuse maps, because I only know that Bayesian filters can be used to estimate the pose of robots.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408706/how-to-fuse-maps-constructed-by-two-different-sensors%EF%BC%9F/) by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can certainly combine maps using Bayes methods if they are transformed into OccupancyGrid maps, here is an example package:

- https://github.com/Nightbot1448/TBMMapMerging

and a paper "Occupancy Grid Map Merging for Multiple Robot Simultaneous Localization and Mapping":

- https://www.sajad-saeedi.ca/uploads/3/8/5/9/38597021/saeedi_ijra_2015.pdf

Some software helps with working with different sensor maps, e.g.

- https://github.com/awesomebytes/occupancy_grid_python
- https://github.com/ANYbotics/grid_map

Could you please link the paper you read? Then we could maybe help you more.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wugeshenhuaking](https://answers.ros.org/users/117137/wugeshenhuaking/) on 2022-10-30**:
@ljaniec  The article I read is here  https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/2203/1/012029/pdf chapter 4.3